# How to call a method without using parameters

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I'm not sure how to call a method without parameters or why I would do it. Some variables aren't declared yet but I'll do it after. The the program is supposed to take user input on their dog's weight and convert it to KG if they enter it in LB then calculate the amount of food to feed the dog.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class hakesgraemeA2Q1{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double weightConversion = convertLBtoKG()
        double weightInLB =   
    }

    public static double convertLBtoKG(double weightInLB)
    {
        return weightInLB * 0.454;
    }


    public static double readWeight()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("do you want to enter weight in kg or lb?, enter k for kg or p for lb ");
        if (userInput == "p"){
            System.out.println("enter your dogs weight in lb's:");
            return Math.round(keyboard.nextDouble() * weightConversion)/ 4f;
        }else if (userInput == "k"){
            System.out.println("enter your dogs weight in kg's:");
            return Math.round(keyboard.nextDouble())/4f;
        }else{
            System.out.println("i can't understant your choice; assuming kg:");  
            return Math.round(keyboard.nextDouble())/4f;
        }
    }
    public static double computeFoodAmount(double weightInKG)
    {
        if (weightInKG < 9.0){
            return weightInKG * 0.22;
        }else if (9.0 <= weightInKG && weightInKG < 32.0){
            return weightInKG * 0.18;
        }else if (32.0 <= weightInKG && weightInKG < 45.0){
            return weightInKG * 0.13;
        }else{
            return weightInKG * 0.09;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're *already* calling methods there without using parameters; for example `keyboard.nextLine()`. Also `convertLBtoKG()` although that should have a parameter. That's all there is to it; just don't put any parameters between the `()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test `String` equality with `==`, you could use [`String#equalsIgnoreCase(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) like

```
if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
  System.out.println("enter your dogs weight in lb's:");
  return Math.round(keyboard.nextDouble() * weightConversion)/ 4f;
} else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("k")) {
  System.out.println("enter your dogs weight in kg's:");
  return Math.round(keyboard.nextDouble())/4f;
} else {
  System.out.println("i can't understant your choice; assuming kg:");  
  return Math.round(keyboard.nextDouble())/4f;
}
```

And to assign the results of `readWeight()` to `weightInLB` you could do

```
double weightInLB = readWeight();
```

Also, this

```
double weightConversion = convertLBtoKG()
```

requires a `double` to be passed to `convertLBtoKG()` because it takes a `double`.

Comment: Hate to downvote you but you didn't really answer the question at all, something like this should've been put in a comment or added to your answer

Comment: Cool, its good now, but I would expand a bit more on that readWeight() method

Answer (score 0):

If a method is without parameters, you just have a set of empty brackets, such as

```
double weight = readWeight();
```

You would generally use a method without parameters if you don't foresee said method having varying inputs. Parameters are generally inputs into a function, where a bunch of stuff happens and then a value is returned. If the inputs are going to be the same, no matter the case, then there may not be a use for a parameter. For example, in your readWeight method, you don't have an external input coming into the function, so having no parameters makes sense. But your convertLBtoKG method requires an external input when the method is called because you have to convert a weight to the correct unit of measurement, then return it back.